# netsnmp.snmpset выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x, snmp

Пытаюсь написать программу, управляющую комплексом устройств по SNMP. В качестве языка программирования использую Python 3. Чтение SNMP-переменных из управляемых устройств идёт нормально. Никак не получается выполнить *netsnmp.snmpset*. Пример:

```
>>> import netsnmp
>>> x1 = '11:22:33:44:55:66'
>>> ss = netsnmp.Session(Version = 2, DestHost = '172.17.132.73', Community="public")
>>> tag = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.<Моя фирма>.5.1.2.1.3.10.1'
>>> vb = netsnmp.Varbind(tag, '0', x1, 'STRING')
>>> snmpe = netsnmp.snmpset(vb, ss)
```

Выдаётся следуюшая ошибка:

> ```
> Traceback (innermost last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py", line 246, in snmpset
>     var_list.append(Varbind(arg))
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/netsnmp/client.py", line 64, in __init__
>     match = regex.match(tag)
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
> ```

Если посмотреть указанные в выдаче исходы, то видно, что ругань идёт на поле *tag* в объекте *vb*. Но он - точно STRING !!!. Так что смысл сообщения об ошибке мне совершенно не понятен. Я пытался убирать начальную точку в OID, пытался сам дописывать "0" в конце - никакого эффекта.

Что за мистика ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
snmpe = snmpset(vb, Version=2, DestHost='172.17.132.73', Community="public")
```

---

Пришлось [смотреть код](https://github.com/travelping/net-snmp/blob/master/python/netsnmp/client.py#L220) библиотеки:

```
def snmpset(*args, **kargs):
    sess = Session(**kargs)
    var_list = VarList()
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, netsnmp.client.Varbind):
            var_list.append(arg)
        else:
            var_list.append(Varbind(arg))
    res = sess.set(var_list)
    return res
```

Тут видно, что все, что передается в функцию в виде списка параметров (args) считаются `Varbind`, а именованные параметры (`kargs`) являются параметрами `Session`.

Поэтому, при выполнении `netsnmp.snmpset(vb, ss)` объект в `ss` (`Session`) не прошел проверку `if isinstance(arg, netsnmp.client.Varbind):` и попал в конструктор `Varbind` как `tag`:

```
class Varbind(object):
    def __init__(self, tag=None, iid=None, val=None, type=None):
        self.tag = STR(tag)
        self.iid = STR(iid)
        self.val = STR(val)
        self.type = STR(type)
        # parse iid out of tag if needed
        if iid == None and tag != None:
            regex = re.compile(r'^((?:\.\d+)+|(?:\w+(?:[-:]*\w+)+))\.?(.*)$')
            match = regex.match(tag)
            if match:
                (self.tag, self.iid) = match.group(1,2)

    ...
```

Ну, и как было в ошибке, `regex.match` работает с строками и байтами.

Comment: Не думаю, что это решит проблему... По следующим причинам:

Comment: 1) Я начинал писать этот код именно в таком синтаксисе.  Потом исправил на то, что показал,  просто для сокращения объёма кода.

Comment: А вы запускали то, что я вам в ответе написал?

Comment: 2) Проверка *if isinstance(arg, netsnmp.client.Varbind):* проверяет переменную *arg* - элемент ПЕРВОГО параметра. А описание сесси - это второй параметр. Он тут непричём.

Comment: Еще раз, вы мой код в ответе запускали? Я ведь писал в ответе когда вы написали `netsnmp.snmpset(vb, ss)`, то в `*args` будет лежать список `[vb, ss]`. Этот список в цикле будет перебираться и когда он дойдет до второго элемента, в котором лежит Session, будет ошибка

Comment: 3) Разумеется - запускал!  Эффект оказался неожиданным. Первое: старое сообщение об ошибке ушло. Второе: появилось совсем короткое сообщение: *error: set: no type found for object*, которое выдаёт неизвестно - кто. И третье: переменная на девайсе своё значение НЕ меняет, хотя УТИЛИТОЙ snmpset оно меняется на раз-два...

Comment: Выходит, что я был прав и мой ответ исправил ошибку в вопросе

Comment: **в *args будет лежать список [vb, ss]** - почему Вы так думаете?

Comment: Потому что так работает `*args` в параметрах функций. Это часть синтаксиса питона. Берете функцию `def foo(*args, **kwargs)`, когда вы ее вызовите с такими параметрами: `foo(1, 2, 3, flag=True, name="Bar")`, то в этой функции `args=[1, 2 ,3]`, а `kwargs={"flag": True, "name": "Bar"}`. Поэтому параметры без имени попали в цикл, а именованные параметры были переданы в конструктор Session. Вообще, эти два специальных параметрах могут называться как угодно, главное -- количество `*`. `*` -- список (или кортеж, нужно смотреть), ** -- словарь

Comment: В `*args` будет все-таки кортеж лежать, но от списка он ничем в этой ситуации не отличается. @Sergey, теперь стало понятно? :)

Comment: **теперь стало понятно? :) –** - да, спасибо! Одно слово : охренеть! И одна проблема: как-же всё-таки заставить работать мою первую программу на питое ?!

Comment: К сожалению, я не работал с той библиотекой, да и эта тема для меня далекая, поэтому не могу сказать. То, что у вас было в вопросе -- ошибка с питоном, поэтому и разобрался в ней. Создайте лучше новый вопрос с учетом текущего кода и ошибки